# How to read a Subdirectory from External Storage with getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-file, android-fileprovider

I am developing an Android app that should read Files from the External Storage and display them in a Listview; creating the subdirectory on the External Storage works fine. The problem is reading from the Subdirectory of the External Storage and I still haven´t figured out how to solve this problem. The Listview displays all the subdirectories of the External Storage and I just want to display the content in one particular subdirectory. The problem consists in "casting" a String into a File Object, which is obviously not possible. Do I really need to open a FileInputStream for that? Any help or hints would be very much appreciated.

I tried to attach the subdirectory as a string to the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() method, lik this: 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Audio";

```
mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation); 
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Audio";
fileNameList = getFileListfromSDCard();
mAdapter = new FlAdapter(this, R.layout.fl_list_item, fileNameList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The error message:

error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to File

Comment: maybe try: 
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Audio");

Answer (score 1):

Because **getExternalStorageDirectory()** returns **String**, you need to convert it to file before assigning it to file.
You can try like this.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Audio");
```

Comment: Thanks so far - I have converted it to file before assigning it to file, now I get the following error message:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File[] java.io.File.listFiles()' on a null object reference
        at gmbh.webagenten.tunelizer.ListActivity.getFileListfromSDCard

Comment: can you please make sure that specified path  was exists and also check case sensitive like /Audio or /audio